# Google Cloud from_service_account_json env variables

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a Python Cloud Function that will push data into BigQuery on a Google Cloud Storage bucket trigger.

Would like to avoid pushing the JSON file to GCS and save the values in the Cloud Function environment variables. However, not sure how to use them to authenticate. [The documentation says to use the file path string.](https://google-cloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.from_service_account_json.html)

Is there any way to do this? Does it even matter?

Currently using the file path and it is working, but thought it would be more secure to use environment variables.

Comment: The best way is to use the --service-account option and do not distribute credentials at all. I wrote an article on this topic for Cloud Run. Almost exactly the same for Functions. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-identity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the the storage bucket, Cloud Function and BigQuery database are all within the same project, you shouldn't need to use service account credentials at all, it will implicitly use the same service account for the project.

If you do need to use service accounts to work across different products, explicitly specifying a service account with the `--service-account` flag would be ideal. See [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) for more details.

Comment: if I use bigquery.Client(), it gives an error.
even though they are all in the same project.

Comment: What's the error? Can you share some code showing how you're creating the client, and the full error message?

Comment: well, the only line of code to connect I have is this;
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

before I had...
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')
this worked. however, I thought that the json file wouldn't be required if in same project.

this is the error;
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.

Comment: Can you include the entire Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is storing it in a Cloud Object store and pulling it down on API start.

An example being amazon s3, download file, then pass the file to google cloud method/function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. At the moment I have around 5 functions that use the same credentials, and each of them has this file. Pulling it down when function starts sounds good to me.

Comment: Its much better for me than distributing the file to each employee.